# Fieldset left and right css

Tags: html, css, forms, fieldset

I have a form and I need to show the info like this:

Your name   Your address
 Your email  Your password
             Submit

Now I got something like this:

```
<fieldset class="left">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*"/>

    <input type="email" id="email" size="50" placeholder="Your Email*"/>

</fieldset>
<fieldset class="right">
    <input type="text" id="tel" size="50" placeholder="Your address*"/>

    <input type="text" id="cel" size="50" placeholder="Your password*"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
```

My class:

```
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}
```

But it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

And the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5fG/

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not specify your problem. Please, show some effort in specifying your problem so we can be sure that we understand what you try to achieve, what have you tried and how did you fail.

Comment: Hello Lajos, i have added in my post the demo so you can see how it is working right now...so i dont know what you mean with: "Please, show some effort in specifying your problem" i think it´s clear, i want to show one fieldset on left and other on right ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the "size" settings of your input fields. Change them all to 20 and they do what you want.

The comment above is minimally helpful, so let me see if I can give you something substantive.

1. In this case, I don't think table layout is that bad of a thing. The data are "kind-of" tabular.
2. You'll have to widen your page, or shrink the input elements down to the minimum size possible.
3. Do you really need two sets of fieldsets?
4. Can you get away with a small font? Are the fields in a popup?